# free'ing results in crash

Tags: c, free, strdup

What is the difference between:

**Case1:**

```
    char* strings[100];
    strings[0]=malloc(100);
    char str[100]="AAA";
    strings[0]=strdup(str);
    free(strings[0]);
```

**Case2:**

```
    char* strings[100];
    strings[0]=malloc(100);
    strings[0]="AAA";
    free(strings[0]);
```

Case2 results in a crash.
`strdup` is as good as `malloc` followed by `strcpy`. Why should second case crash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strings[0]="AAA";` does not copy the contents `AAA` into the memory to which `string[0]` points, it rather lets `strings[0]` point to string literal `"AAAA"`; and freeing a string literal is undefined behaviour, since you are freeing memory which has not been allocated through `malloc` before. Note that you lost any access to your previously `malloc`ed memory once statement `strings[0]="AAA"` has been executed.

To copy the contents into the `malloc`ed memory, write `strcpy(strings[0],"AAA")`. Then the `free` should be no problem any more.

Answer (score 2):

It would crash simply because it's what (usually, the behavior is undefined) happens when you try to free a pointer that is not pointing at memory that can be freed. Read more about string literals here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1704433/6699433

And both of your examples are very badly written, since the malloc is simply never used.

```
char* strings[100];
strings[0]=malloc(100);
char str[100]="AAA";
strings[0]=strdup(str);
free(strings[0]);
```

is equivalent to

```
char* strings[100];
char str[100]="AAA";
strings[0]=strdup(str);
free(strings[0]);
```

and

```
char* strings[100];
strings[0]=malloc(100);
strings[0]="AAA";
free(strings[0]);
```

is equivalent to

```
char* strings[100];
strings[0]="AAA";
free(strings[0]);
```

Note that "equivalent" is not 100% correct, since you have side effects. I just wanted to show that some lines are completely pointless since you don't use result before reassigning the variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
strings[0]=malloc(100);
```

Here `strings[0]` is a pointer to newly allocated memory. Then, however, you do `strings[0]="AAA";` which causes it to point to `"AAA"`, a string in read-only memory. Your allocated memory is now leaked. Then you try to free the `"AAA"`, which you can't do because that's read-only memory.

In the first snippet it works because you release the duped memory, but you're still leaking the `malloc` allocated memory.